# How to focus a Material UI Textfield on button click?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to focus a Textfield after clicking a button. I tried to use autoFocus but it did not work out: [Example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4j81n6px17)

```
  <div>
    <button onclick={() => this.setState({ focus: true })}>
      Click to focus Textfield
    </button>
    <br />
    <TextField
      label="My Textfield"
      id="mui-theme-provider-input"
      autoFocus={this.state.focus}
    />
  </div>
```

Comment: `autoFocus` is for when it first appears. You can give it a ref and use `.focus()`. You could access it directly via its `id`, though in React a ref is much preferred

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use a ref, see https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  focusTextInput() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    // tell React that we want to associate the <input> ref
    // with the `textInput` that we created in the constructor
    return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.focusTextInput}>
            Click to focus Textfield
          </button>
       <br />
       <TextField
         label="My Textfield"
         id="mui-theme-provider-input"
         inputRef={this.textInput} 
       />
     </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Updated ref to inputRef for Material-UI v3.6.1.

Comment: I'm on @material-ui 1.12.3 and needed to use `inputRef` instead of `ref` in the `TextField` props

Comment: This doesn't set the border width to the textfield's focused width. When you focus on an input the border width increases from 1px to 2px, but doing this method results in the border width staying at 1px.

Answer (score 13):

if you are using a stateless functional component then you can use react hooks.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

let MyFunctional = (props) => {

  let textInput = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            textInput.current.focus();
          }, 100);
        }}
      >
        Focus TextField
      </Button>
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        required
        inputRef={textInput}
        name="firstName"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Your First Name"
        label="First Name"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Material-ui `<TextField/>` with react functional Component, you can implement `focus` using `inputRef`. The trick here is the if condition `if(input != null)`. You can simply do:

```
<TextField
    variant="filled"
    inputRef={(input) => {
      if(input != null) {
         input.focus();
      }
    }}
/>
```

Here is an working example for you. [CodeSandBox- Material-ui-TextFieldFocus](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-textfieldfocus-jz9gb?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

First, `onclick` must be correct like `onClick`,
then if you want to use it inline your `JSX` code, it can help. 
I tested it with react 16, it works.

```
 <button onClick={() => this.myTextField.focus()}>
    Click to focus Textfield
 </button>

<TextField
       label="My Textfield"
       id="mui-theme-provider-input"
       inputRef={(el) => (this.myTextField = el)} />
```