# How to focus on Material UI TextField using useRef hooks when a button is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I have a similar problem as [How to focus a Material UI Textfield on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222988/how-to-focus-a-material-ui-textfield-on-button-click) but I couldn't solve the problem with the answers provided.

Here's the code. Basically, all of the textfields are disabled. When edit profile button is clicked, it will set the `disabled` state for account name to `false` and I would like to focus on that particular field. I'm using the `useRef` hooks to reference out the field but it didn't work.It would only work if I click the button twice.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import PermContactCalendarIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PermContactCalendar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    padding: theme.spacing(5),
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  form: {
    width: "100%", // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
  },
  fixedHeight: {
    height: 1000,
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

export default function AccountPage({ userdata }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [accountName, setAccountName] = useState("");

  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === "accountname") {
      setAccountName(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container component="main">
      <CssBaseline />
      <Paper>
        <div className={classes.paper}>
          <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
            <PermContactCalendarIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            Account & User Settings
          </Typography>
          <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
            <Grid
              container
              direction="column"
              justify="center"
              alignItems="stretch"
              spacing={2}
            >
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Typography color="primary" display="inline" noWrap>
                  Account Name :
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  name="accountname"
                  variant="outlined"
                  fullWidth
                  //   autoFocus
                  onChange={handleOnChange}
                  disabled={disabled}
                  value={accountName}
                  inputRef={inputRef}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Typography color="primary" display="inline" noWrap>
                  E-mail Address :
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  variant="outlined"
                  fullWidth
                  value={userdata.email}
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  disabled={true}
                  //   onChange={handleOnChange}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Typography color="primary" display="inline" noWrap>
                  Account ID :
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  variant="outlined"
                  fullWidth
                  name="id"
                  value={userdata._id}
                  type="text"
                  disabled={true}
                  //   onChange={handleOnChange}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              className={(classes.submit, classes.button)}
              onClick={() => {
                setDisabled(false);
                inputRef.current.focus();
              }}
            >
              Edit Profile
            </Button>
            <Button
              //   type="submit"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              className={(classes.submit, classes.button)}
              onClick={() => {
                setDisabled(true);
              }}
            >
              Save Changes
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in the onClick event handler of the Edit button:

```
() => {
  setDisabled(false);
  inputRef.current.focus();
};
```

You should keep in mind that `setState` is asynchronous. Here is a quote from the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate):

> The setState function is used to update the state. It accepts a new
>   state value and **enqueues** a re-render of the component.

In other words, React promises you `disabled` will be set to `false` sometime in the future, but probably not when the line `inputRef.current.focus()` is executed.

So what you are trying to do is to ask React: *when `disabled` is set to `false`, focus an element*. And this is what `useEffect` hook is for - it lets you perform side effects. So instead of putting `inputRef.current.focus()` right after `setDisabled(false)`, you can set up an `useEffect` hook as follow:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!disabled) {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }
}, [disabled]); // Only run the function if disabled changes
```

Comment: Thanks for your help again! It works now but I'm still confused when to use the useEffect hook. So basically, if we have more than 1 function , it's better to go for useEffect as not to interfere with the main function?

Comment: When some actions need to be done as a result of state change, you should consider using `useEffect`. Those actions can be fetching an API, changing document.title or focusing an element, etc. I recommend reading the React docs about [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).